# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column issue with database table insert

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having an issue with the following code to add records to an 'offer' db table in CodeIgniter..

Database table (mySQL):

```
1  ID           int(11)                                 No         
 2  OfferName   varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No             
 3  OfferLength varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  
 4  OfferTitle  varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  
 5  OfferDescription    varchar(300)    latin1_swedish_ci   No  
 6  OfferURL    varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  
 7  OfferContent    varchar(300)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  
 8  Key varchar(10) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL
```

Method in the model (offer_model.php):

```
public function entry_insert(){

      $data = array(
            'OfferName' => $this->input->post('OfferName'),
            'OfferLength' => $this->input->post('OfferLength'),
            'OfferTitle' => $this->input->post('OfferTitle'),
            'OfferDescription' => $this->input->post('OfferDescription'),
            'OfferURL' => $this->input->post('OfferURL'),
            'OfferContent' => $this->input->post('OfferContent'),
        );

$this->db->insert('offers',$data);

 }
```

Controller:

```
function addOffer() {
    //if the form is submitted
    if ($this->input->post('mysubmit')) {
        //insert data into db using offer_model model

        $this->offer_model->entry_insert();

    }
```

Form in the view:

```
<div class="form">
            <?php echo form_open('newOffer/addOffer'); ?>
            <legend>Please enter details for your new offer</legend>

            <label for="OfferName">Offer Name:  <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferName" id="Offer Name" placeholder="Please enter the name of your offer"/>
            <label for="OfferLength">Offer length:</label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferLength" id="OfferLength" placeholder="Please enter the length of your offer"/>
            <label for="OfferTitle">Offer title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferTitle" id="OfferTitle" placeholder="Please enter the title of your new offer"/>
            <label for="OfferDescription">Offer description: </label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferDescription" id="OfferDescription" placeholder="Please enter a description of your new offer"/>
            <label for="OfferURL">Offer link URL:</label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferURL" id="OfferURL" placeholder="Please enter the URL of your new offer"/>
            <label for="OfferContent">Offer content:</label>
            <input type="text" name="OfferContent" id="OfferContent" placeholder="Please enter the content for your new offer"/>
            <fieldset class="submit_field">
                <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Form'); ?>
            </fieldset>

        </div><!-- end of form div -->
```

Submitting the form results in:

Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'OfferName' in 'field list'

Just can't figure it out as table is there and field names seem to match up?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the insert succeed if you remove `OfferName` from the `$data` array?

Comment: Hi, tried that, it just moves onto next one in the array - OfferLength.

Comment: Is the table name `Offers` or `offers`? It sounds like the table is not named correctly or you're using the wrong database.

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks for help here. It is 'offers'. Works for outputting data in the same table so stumped?

Comment: Get the output of `$this->db->last_query();` and run the query manually. If it works, there is a db connection or user problem. If it doesn't, CI is not producing the correct query.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but may help others going forward.

I was getting this 1054 error in one of my queries.  My query was one line:

```
$q = $this->db->get('table');
```

But for some reason the DB error I got included a query with 28 null where statements which included fields that were not only not called from the query but did not exist in that table (hence the db error).

I did a dump of $this->db:

```
    var_dump($this->db);
```

... and it showed me that the CI ar_where var was indeed full with this strange where data.
I realized that this was coming from the only other query previously executed on the page and then realized why.  That previous db call was being made from a library and therefore used:

```
$this->CI->db->get('someTable');
```

So the previous data was not cleared.  After manually clearing that data from the end of the first library function all worked fine again and the 1054 error was gone.

Also, to address shomz suggestion, if there is a query error, your last_query() will never execute as it comes after a successful query.  Execution halts before that line can be executed with a db error.  In this case it didn't help me either.  But the var_dump($this->db) did help for this purpose!

Answer (score 0):

`echo $this->db->last_query();` will save your life in numerous instances.
You also have a syntax error (trailing comma) in your model:

`'OfferContent' => $this->input->post('OfferContent'),`

Also, you wrote in the first paragraph that the table is called `offer` yet you're inserting into `offers`. Make sure you also have that cleared up.

Comment: So, what does the `echo $this->db->last_query();` say if you put it right below the insert function in your model?

Comment: Hi Shomz, thanks for the pointers. Have done as you suggested apart from table is actually called 'offers'. Still returning Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'OfferName' in 'field list'   ...argh!

Comment: No problem, can you please paste what the echo command I gave you outputs?

Comment: Hi, I added like so: `public function entry_insert(){

          $data = array(
                'OfferName' => $this->input->post('OfferName'),
                'OfferLength' => $this->input->post('OfferLength'),
                'OfferTitle' => $this->input->post('OfferTitle'),
                'OfferDescription' => $this->input->post('OfferDescription'),
                'OfferURL' => $this->input->post('OfferURL'),
                'OfferContent' => $this->input->post('OfferContent')
            );

 $this->db->insert('offers',$data);
        echo $this->db->last_query();
  }`Nothing outputted..

Comment: Hm, either your code is never executed or the page is refreshed right after it... Try adding `die();` right after that last echo command. It should stop the script from executing further.

Comment: Still getting the same 1054 error. It will display data from the database??

Comment: I still need to see the last_query() output... if that's fine, then you don't have the OfferName field in your table (wrong table?).

Answer (score 0):

Write a Query like this :-
$this->db->query("insert into users (username,password) values('$username','$lastname')");

**Variable name should be in single quotes.**

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to explain more precisely your code, why exactly it will fix the problem. Format your code according to the site rules https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help